# issue with artifacts appearing on ubuntu in windows title and in mate terminal

Tags: mate, visual-artifacts

I recently starting seeing artifact such as that when using the mate terminal from ubuntu:

[image]

I also noticed that those started happening on the windows titlebars as well:

[image]

Anyone knows why that is so / how to remedy it ?

Thanks